# How to update two (or more) dependable columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have to update two columns in the same table. Columns contains DATE and TIME separately of the same timepoint. I have to decrease this timepoint by 7 hours and save result back to that 2 columns. I am using this query

```
update wp_2_em_events 
set event_start_time = DATE_FORMAT(
    DATE_SUB(concat(event_start_date,' ',event_start_time), 
        INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 
    '%H:%i:%s'), 
event_start_date = DATE_FORMAT(
    DATE_SUB(concat(event_start_date,' ',event_start_time), 
        INTERVAL 7 HOUR),
    '%Y-%m-%d'),
```

As you can see second column (`event_start_date`) can not be updated properly, because expression use already updated parameter.

Let me know how I can update either both columns simultaneously or store changed datetime to temp variable and use it for both columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using temp variable

```
update wp_2_em_events
set event_start_time = DATE_FORMAT(
     (@t := DATE_SUB(concat(event_start_date,' ',event_start_time), 
          INTERVAL 7 HOUR)),'%H:%i:%s'),
    event_start_date = DATE_FORMAT(@t,'%Y-%m-%d')
```